# Why does echo "a" | wc -m return 2?

Tags: pipe, echo, wc

Why does `echo "a" | wc -m` echo `2`? Other variations in which I try to reduce the number of spaces yield the same result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488655/how-does-the-wc-c-in-linux-work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `wc` counts the newline  `\n` too.

`echo` adds a newline character to end of the output, unless invoked with `-n` option.

Comment: Just realised this -_-